# Snap Scroll to Element only on Scroll Down

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I've come along an issue and needed your guidance. Im willing to perform an animation when I end scrolling on a page (Mousewheel AND Trackpad).

When I stop scrolling, the window should snap to the closest element and that only if window top is less than 100px near the element.

I've tried to use any of the plugins such as fullpage.js, snapscroll and skrollr  which have this featured integrated on their core package, however it didn't fit my needs, since none of them had proper documentation regarding the direction of scrolling or amount of scrolling per se.

I've been trying to include the aforementioned conditions but with no success:

- **Up or Down Direction of Scrolling**
- **A fixed amount to when the snapping shall happen**

This is my HTML structure:

```
<div class="section" id="section-1">
  content here
</div>
<div class="section" id="section-2">
  content here
</div>
<div class="section" id="section-3">
  content here
</div>
<div class="section" id="section-4">
  content here
</div>
```

This is my jQuery script so far:

```
var items = $(".section");
var animating = false;
var lastScrollTop = 0;

$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
      // downscroll code
      console.log('We are scrolling down!');
      clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
      if (!animating) {
        $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
          items.each(function(key, value) {
             animating = true;
             $('body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(value).offset().top + 'px'
             }, 250);
             setTimeout(function() {
                animating = false;
             }, 300);
           return true;
        });
      }, 1200));
    };
} else {
  console.log('We are scrolling down!');
}
  lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Alvaro - I've been using Fullpage.Js but it doesn't offer the very same functionality based on my conditions. If it would, I would've added the tag.

Comment: No problem. Removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i hope that's what you're looking for

```
var timeout = 1200;
var timer;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        $(".section").each(function() {
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            var offset = $(this).offset().top;
            if(offset-scrollTop < 100 && offset-scrollTop > -100) {
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top},'slow');
                return;
            }
        });
    }, timeout);
});
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vqakpboe/1/)

Comment: Yeah, this is basically what I've been looking for all the time. I really appreciate your help man. After days of suffering u came to the rescue :)

Comment: I found your answer as the closest of what I'm looking for, I spent about a week googling and finally posted a question, it is been up-voted but no one is provide a useful solution so far, would you mind to take a [look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52058702/css-scroll-snap-div-to-div-with-no-dimensions)? @ApfelPresse